# How can I collect key presses while time is passing?

Tags: c#

I'd like to write a loop that collects key presses (from the keyboard) and does an action every second or so.  There would be some way of reading from the keyboard:

```
whenever (Console.KeyPressed != null) {
    input_buffer.Add(Console.KeyPressed);
}
```

And there would be some loop happening:

```
while (!done) {
    if (input_buffer.NotEmpty()) { do_stuff(input_buffer.Pop()); }
    do_other_stuff();
    wait(0.5 seconds);
}
```

So if the user presses a key, it gets dealt with during the next update.  If they don't press a key, the next update happens anyhow.

Comment: Do you want this to capture keyboard events within your app, or in all of Windows?

Comment: @JoshSmeaton, just from within this app.

Comment: @Joe What did you think of my answer? You're not on .Net 4?

Comment: @ChristofferLette, it *looks* good, but I haven't had a chance to try it yet.  This weekend I'll be back on that project, and I'll give it a try.  If it's as good as it looks, I'll accept it as the best answer.

Comment: Got any feedback for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on .Net 4 you can use the code below. It uses `ConcurrentQueue` for storing the keypresses, `ManualResetEventSlim` for signaling, and `Task` from the Task Parallel Library for running the two code parts asynchronously.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static ConcurrentQueue<ConsoleKeyInfo> _keypresses = new ConcurrentQueue<ConsoleKeyInfo>();
        private static ManualResetEventSlim _stopEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim();

        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

            var keyReaderTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(ReadKeys);
            var keyProcessingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessKeys);

            _stopEvent.Wait();
            keyReaderTask.Wait();
            keyProcessingTask.Wait();
        }

        public static void ReadKeys()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

                if (keyInfo.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control && keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
                {
                    break;
                }

                _keypresses.Enqueue(keyInfo);
            }

            _stopEvent.Set();
        }

        public static void ProcessKeys()
        {
            while (!_stopEvent.IsSet)
            {
                if (!_keypresses.IsEmpty)
                {
                    Console.Write("Keys: ");

                    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
                    while (_keypresses.TryDequeue(out keyInfo))
                    {
                        Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                _stopEvent.Wait(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```